# fixed element not remaining fixed with parralax scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am creating a page that is a slideshow with several images and a parallax scrolling effect. The scrolling is working fine, however I want to have the buttons for the music control fixed on the top, however the buttons will not stay fixed no matter what I do.

my images are set up like this:

```
.first {
  display: flex;
 
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
background-image: url('./orange.png');
background-size: 100% 100%;

}
```

And my header is called 'dock' and has the following code

```
<div className="  dock">
    {" "}
    <button className="button" onClick={Playit}>
      Play Audio
    </button>{" "}
 
    <button className="button2" onClick={Stopit}>
      Pause Audio
    </button>
  </div>
CSS 
.dock {
 top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 99;
position: fixed !important;
}
```

This is my first time working with any kind of scroll effects. I am unsure why the two buttons on the top will not remain fixed.
Any advice you have will be appreciated.

 A codesandbox is available here [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-gareth-tm9g5?file=/src/dock.js)

 Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am unsure why the two buttons on the top will not remain fixed.

Moving the music controls *out* of the 3d app container will respect the fixed positioning.

As for "why" (from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#values)):

> **fixed**
>
> ...It is positioned relative to the initial containing block established by the viewport, *except when one of its ancestors has a `transform`, **`perspective`**, or `filter` property set to something other than none (see the CSS Transforms Spec), in which case **that ancestor behaves as the containing block.*** [emphasis mine]

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  background: bisque;
}

.app {
  perspective: 1px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.box {
  height: 100vh;
  border: 4px solid lavender;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header><button>Play me</button></header>
<section class="app">
  <div class="box">Thing 1</div>
  <div class="box">Thing 2</div>
  <div class="box">Thing 3</div>
</section>
```

Comment: @imstupidpleasehelp note the overlap of the controls on the top box in my example. s.kuznetsov's suggestion `position: sticky` has the benefit of preventing this overlap with the content is scrolled to the very top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

The `position: fixed` has a slightly different purpose. If you need a *fixed* element inside a container then better use `position: sticky` instead of `position: fixed`. Just add these rules to `.dock`  selector:

```
position: sticky
top: 0
z-index: 9999
```

As here:

```
.dock {
  background-color: red;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```